# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon on debian buster on wsl 2

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, debian-buster, wsl-2

I am trying to install docker on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) 2 (running on Windows Home build 19033.1). I installed wsl2 as per the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-install and installed debian from the Windows Store, which is debian 10 (buster). It is running on wsl 2 as proven by this:

> wsl -l -v
>     NAME      STATE           VERSION
>   * Debian    Running         2
>
> $ cat /etc/os-release
>   PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
>   NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
>   VERSION_ID="10"
>   VERSION="10 (buster)"
>   VERSION_CODENAME=buster
>   ID=debian
>   HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
>   SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
>   BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

I followed instructions at https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-docker-on-debian-10-buster-linux to install docker:

> sudo apt install docker.io
>   sudo docker run hello-world
>   docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.

Looked to see if docker was running:

> sudo service docker status
>   [FAIL] Docker is not running ... failed!

So I try to restart docker daemon:

> $ sudo service docker restart
>   grep: /etc/fstab: No such file or directory
>   [ ok ] Starting Docker: docker.

Found another [article on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397435/docker-start-failed-because-etc-fstab-not-found) saying I could solve that by issuing:

> sudo touch /etc/fstab

and that seemed to work (grep error is no longer appearing):

> $ sudo service docker restart
>   [ ok ] Starting Docker: docker.

But I'm still getting the same problem:

> $ sudo docker run hello-world
>   docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.

I looked at the docker log and its full of errors:

```
$ cat /var/log/docker.log | grep -i error  
time="2019-11-28T21:48:51.725383200Z" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter"  
time="2019-11-28T21:48:51.726777600Z" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs" error="modprobe aufs failed: \"modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.19.84-microsoft-standard/modules.dep.bin'\\nmodprobe: FATAL: Module aufs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.84-microsoft-standard\\n\": exit status 1"  
time="2019-11-28T21:48:51.726982500Z" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter"  
time="2019-11-28T21:48:51.727010800Z" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter aufs in metadata plugin" error="modprobe aufs failed: \"modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.19.84-microsoft-standard/modules.dep.bin'\\nmodprobe: FATAL: Module aufs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.84-microsoft-standard\\n\": exit status 1"  
time="2019-11-28T21:48:51.727022700Z" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter zfs in metadata plugin" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter"  
time="2019-11-28T21:48:51.727031100Z" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter btrfs in metadata plugin" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter"  
time="2019-11-28T21:48:51.744791900Z" level=warning msg="Running modprobe nf_nat failed with message: `modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.19.84-microsoft-standard/modules.dep.bin'\nmodprobe: WARNING: Module nf_nat not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.84-microsoft-standard`, error: exit status 1"  
time="2019-11-28T21:48:51.746095200Z" level=warning msg="Running modprobe xt_conntrack failed with message: `modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.19.84-microsoft-standard/modules.dep.bin'\nmodprobe: WARNING: Module xt_conntrack not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.84-microsoft-standard`, error: exit status 1"  
time="2019-11-28T21:48:51.768996800Z" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="<nil>" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby  
time="2019-11-28T21:48:51.769171500Z" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables):  CHAIN_ADD failed (No such file or directory): chain PREROUTING
```

Bit lost as to what the problem is here. Hoping someone can advise?

---

I followed the excellent advice from @s-x-tan below who recommended following instructions at https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/using-wsl2/#updating-kernel. Those instructions say to issue:

```
# This assumes Ubuntu or Debian, a different step may be needed for RPM based distributions
sudo apt install build-essential flex bison libssl-dev libelf-dev
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel.git
cd WSL2-Linux-Kernel
make -j4 KCONFIG_CONFIG=Microsoft/config-wsl
mkdir /mnt/c/linuxtemp
cp arch/x86_x64/boot/bzImage /mnt/c/linuxtemp/
```

Unfortunately the commands don't produce the same dir strucuture that that `cp` command is expecting. I do not have `arch/x86_x64/` dir. I do have an `arch/x86` dir but that doesn't contain `boot/bzImage`:

```
jamiet@DESKTOP-GA45TGH:/mnt/c/Users/jamie/git/github/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel$ ls arch/x86/boot/
a20.c       code16gcc.h  cpuflags.h              install.sh      pm.c      string.h      video.c
apm.c       compressed   ctype.h                 main.c          pmjump.S  tools         video.h
bioscall.S  copy.S       early_serial_console.c  Makefile        printf.c  tty.c         video-mode.c
bitops.h    cpu.c        edd.c                   memory.c        regs.c    version.c     video-vesa.c
boot.h      cpucheck.c   genimage.sh             mkcpustr.c      setup.ld  vesa.h        video-vga.c
cmdline.c   cpuflags.c   header.S                mtools.conf.in  string.c  video-bios.c
```

I followed the exact instructions so can only guess that the repo has changed since https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/using-wsl2/#updating-kernel was written. In case it helps, here are the dirs in `arch`:

```
jamiet@DESKTOP-GA45TGH:/mnt/c/Users/jamie/git/github/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel$ ls arch/
alpha  arm    c6x    hexagon  Kconfig  microblaze  nds32  openrisc  powerpc  s390  sparc  unicore32  xtensa
arc    arm64  h8300  ia64     m68k     mips        nios2  parisc    riscv    sh    um     x86
```

Still hoping for some clarity from someone.

Comment: Are you sure you are using WSL2? What is the full Windows 10 version number? Docker daemon needs to be started from systemd. There is no official recommended way to do it. Do you accept to do some "unoficial" commands?

Comment: Hi, thx for the reply. Yes its wsl 2, I've updated the post to reflect this and also included the Windows10 build number. I'm fine with trying anything leftfield if it gets this working.

Answer (score 6):

Posting here in case anyone one else has this issue as I just did. It seems to be the same problem as https://superuser.com/questions/1468316/which-kernel-moduules-are-really-needed-for-docker-installation

As per that answer, after running:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
sudo update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy
```

I was able to start start the docker service.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue, because Debian doesn't have the modules of **4.19.84-microsoft-standard** kernel installed. Unfortunately Microsoft doesn't provide pre-built lib/modules for this kernel, you have to build the kernel using the source code from https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel.

I tried kernel 4.9.0-11-amd64 extracted from Debian image as the custom kernel (in .wslconfig) but WSL2 couldn't boot it up. So there is no other way around.

Here are the instructions:
https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/using-wsl2/#updating-kernel

After built the kernel, run **sudo make modules_install**, then run docker:

*docker run hello-world

Hello from Docker!

This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.*

Comment: thx for the reply. I tried your suggestion but stumbled. I updated the post above accordingly.